# How to limit data transfer on the database level or account level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

It's possible to somehow control/manage/limit the amount of data that can be transferred for specific database or login/account/role? The issue is that we have shared database and multiple applications connects to that database but if any application will use all the database resources (due to developer mistake or high usage) it has impact on the whole server. How to prevent this situation, any idea?

PS: The server is SQL Server 2016 and run on-premise and applications connects from Microsoft Power Apps.

Comment: Please specify the version, edition and type (on premise, cloud, etc.) of SQL Server you are using, the best answer will vary depending on that.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you but it does not, your answer is about limiting whole SQL Server instead of specific account / database and in WSRM documentation it says  "Manage system resources ... per process, per user, per Remote Desktop Services session, or per IIS app pool" but there is no mention about SQL Server except collecting database usage.

Comment: It was intended to draw your attention to the Resource Governor, but apparently it failed.

Comment: Oh sorry, looking into Resource Governor now  I am not sure if we have enterprise edition, I will check, thank you.